# NonUniformImage with nonlinear axes

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have an image in a nonuniform grid, and want to plot it with one of the axes scaled logarithmically. This is possible for `imshow`, however that requires regularly spaced data. I can plot my irregularly gridded data with `NonUniformImage`, however setting `ax.set_xscale('log')` only has an effect on the axis, not the image itself.

Is this possible to achieve with `NonUniformImage`, or even possible at all? Here is some code that shows what I mean (top row is `imshow`, bottom is `NonUniformImage`).

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
from matplotlib.image import NonUniformImage

# Linear x array for cell centers:
x = np.linspace(1, 10, 10) 

# Highly nonlinear x array:
x2 = x**3

# Linear y-array
y = np.linspace(1, 10, 10) 
z = np.sqrt(x[np.newaxis, :]**2 + y[:, np.newaxis]**2)


fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=2)
fig.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.07, hspace=0.3)

# Uniform Grid, linear x-axis
ax = axs[0, 0]
im = ax.imshow(z, extent=(1, 10, 1, 10), aspect='auto',origin='lower')
ax.set_title("Uniform Grid, linear x-axis")

# Uniform Grid, log x-axis (image changes)
ax = axs[0, 1]
im = ax.imshow(z, extent=(1, 10, 1, 10),aspect='auto',origin='lower')
ax.set_xscale('log')
ax.set_title('Uniform Grid, log x-axis')

# Correct ticklabel formatting
from matplotlib.ticker import StrMethodFormatter, NullFormatter
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(StrMethodFormatter('{x:.0f}'))
ax.xaxis.set_minor_formatter(NullFormatter())

# NonUniform Grid, linear x-axis
ax = axs[1, 0]
im = NonUniformImage(ax, interpolation='nearest', extent=(1, 1000, 1, 10))
im.set_data(x2, y, z)
ax.images.append(im)
ax.set_xlim(1, 1000)
ax.set_ylim(1, 10) 
ax.set_title('NonUniform Grid, lin x-axis')

# NonUniform Grid, logarithmic x-axis (this doesn't work as intended)
ax = axs[1, 1]
im = NonUniformImage(ax, interpolation='nearest', extent=(1, 1000, 1, 10))
im.set_data(x2, y, z)
ax.images.append(im)
ax.set_xlim(1, 1000)
ax.set_ylim(1, 10) 
ax.set_xscale('log')
ax.set_title('NonUniform Grid, log x-axis')

plt.show()
```

[image: Resulting figure]

Comment: Thank you for providing a MCVE. How does the desired image look? This code looks similar to the official code [here](https://matplotlib.org/1.3.0/examples/pylab_examples/image_nonuniform.html). Can you try using `interpolation='bilinear'` for the last case as done in the example?

Comment: basically the problem is that the image is rendered using square coords which are not transformed by the axis transformation, then the bounding box is linearly scaled to axes coords so the data lines up (if the axes coords are also linear). In this case the lack of a second transform misaligns the data.

Comment: This could be considered a bug that `mpl.image._ImageBase` does not query the axes transforms for the purpose of aligning all the data, only the bounding box, but realistically to solve your problem, you should just transform your input data before feeding it to `NonUniformImage`

Comment: My data is linear on the x-axis, and logarithmically spaced on the y-axis. I have now set `interpolation='bilinear`. 

Here is the figure that my program produces for `ax.set_xscale('linear')`

[Image 1](https://i.imgur.com/y9kRM9l.png)

and here is the figure that my program produces for `ax.set_xscale('log')`


[Image 2](https://i.imgur.com/fKf27n4.png)

Note that just the axis changes, not the image

Comment: @Bazingaa Sorry I misunderstood your request - yes the problem is the same for this interpolation method.

Comment: @Aaron: Thanks! I just submitted it as a [bug](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/13442) through github, lets see what happens.

Comment: I'm having second thoughts on whether it's really a bug, because one of the purposes of the `mpl.image` class is to embed regular images in graphs, where the pixel values don't necessarily have any relation to their position on the axes. I think what you need to do here is just do a bit of math beforehand: `im.set_data(np.log10(x2)*1000/3, y, z)`

Comment: Why not just use `pcolormesh`?